# How can I change the line color of embedded SVGs in a PDF without rasterizing the images?

Tags: pdf, svg

I have PDFs with nothing but embedded SVGs. The SVGs have a line color of #000000 but I'd like to update the SVGs in the PDF to have a line color of #b5b5b5 without having to rasterize them. Is this possible with a tool like ghostscript, inkscape, or imagemagick?

Answer (score 0):

In Inkscape, you can open the PDF, then Edit > Select All in All Layers. After they are all selected, you can modify the stroke value as you would any SVG, then simply save the document.

I was hoping for a bash option, and I'm sure there would be one, but this works well enough.